# Implement code after convert Java to Kotlin error

Tags: android, kotlin

I already try to found if this problem was here on *StackoverFlow*, before I came here.
I am try to convert a *Java* class to *Kotlin* but *Android Studio* does not do it very well.

I try to do it manually but not success.

This is the original code in *Java*

```
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
    }
```

here is the code converted by *Android Studio*

```
    private fun appendHex(sb: StringBuffer, b: Byte) {
        sb.append(HEX[b shr 4 and 0x0f]).append(HEX[b and 0x0f])
    }
```

the error is after convert, *Android Studio* does not recognize `shr` & `and`, when I press *ALT+ENTER* it shows a popup to `Create extension function Byte.shr` and after press enter, it create a this private fun:

```
private infix fun Byte.shr(i: Int): Any {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

the same to `and` but now on popup it has an `Import` option that point to `import kotlin.experimental.and` or create private fun:

```
private infix fun Any.and(i: Int): Int {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

after do this and run my app the class is not working with message `An operation is not implemented: not implemented`

How to implement this to work?

Comment: What is `HEX`? Is it some kind of constant? I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but for me "kotlin way" to do this is to create extension function on `StringBuffer`. Something like `fun StringBuffer.appendHexByte(b: Byte)`.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/47925781/3934789

Comment: yes, it is a constant, class is under https://gist.github.com/ozzpy/baaa73697c9170137788dd8951dc0fd3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the operators (infix functions) [`shr`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/shr.html) and [`and`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/and.html) for the type `Int` (and `Long`) in Kotlin. 
Just change `b` with `b.toInt()`:

```
private fun appendHex(sb: StringBuffer, b: Byte) {
    sb.append(HEX[b.toInt() shr 4 and 0x0f]).append(HEX[b.toInt() and 0x0f])
}
```